# Is the FAA expected to issue more regulations soon on drone usage in rural areas?

Tags: faa-regulations, unmanned-aerial-vehicle

There are exponential increases in funding for small drone startups.  When is the next publication period for the FAA to issue regulations on use of small drones in suburban areas?

Comment: [Drones and Model Aircraft](https://drones.stackexchange.com/) may be a good place for this question...

Comment: I think this site is a better place for this question.  It's not outside of the site guidelines, and if you look at Drones and Model Aircraft  SE, you'll see it's almost entirely about technical "what's the best way to do this" questions.

Comment: Your question is confusing. The title asks about "rural areas" while the body of the post asks about "suburban areas". The question already doesn't show any evidence of an attempt at research, but it's not even clear what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is really an aviation question because you're asking about how and when Federal agencies make regulations, and you might get a better answer to that on [law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

But having said that, agencies are required to publish their rulemaking plans twice a year. You can find them in the "[unified agenda](https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaMain)" for that agency. If you look at the Department of Transportation agenda there are currently six FAA rules that include "unmanned aircraft" in their title. Four are already final, the other two are:

- Safe and Secure Operations of Small Unmanned Aircraft Systems
- Prohibit or Restrict the Operation of an Unmanned Aircraft in Close Proximity to a Fixed Site Facility

I haven't read them and I have no idea about the timeline for them or if they include anything about rural operations specifically.

Comment: The two that are not final are: https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaViewRule?pubId=202010&RIN=2120-AL26 , https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaViewRule?pubId=202010&RIN=2120-AL33.  Three that are final are https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaViewRule?pubId=202010&RIN=2120-AK85 , https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaViewRule?pubId=202010&RIN=2120-AL31 , https://www.reginfo.gov/public/do/eAgendaViewRule?pubId=202010&RIN=2120-AL32 .  I must have missed one if four are final--